# graphql/graphcool: How to write a mutation that links both a one:one and a one:many relationship

Tags: graphql, graphcool

I have a schema as follows:

```
type Artist @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  name: String! @isUnique
  songkickId: String
  shows: [Show!]! @relation(name: "ArtistShow")
}

type Show @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  name: String
  songkickId: String
  date: DateTime! 
  soldOut: Boolean!
  pit: Boolean!
  ages: String!
  price: String!
  multiDay: Boolean!
  artists: [Artist!]! @relation(name: "ArtistShow")
  venue: Venue! @relation(name: "ShowVenue")
}

type Venue @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  name: String! @isUnique
  address: String
  latitude: Float
  longitude: Float
  metro: String
  songkickId: String @isUnique
  shows: [Show!]! @relation(name: "ShowVenue")
}
```

I have written mutations that, given JSON data, create `Artist`s and `Venue`s and return those to me.

At the time that I want to create a `Show`, I have:

1. An array of `Artist` IDs
2. An ID for a `Venue`
3. All required info to populate the rest of the `Show` data (in an object called `showInfo`)

I have a mutation that looks like this:

```
        mutation: gql`
            mutation {
                createShow(
                    date: "${showInfo.date}"
                    soldOut: ${showInfo.soldOut}
                    pit: ${showInfo.pit}
                    ages: "${showInfo.ages}"
                    price: "${showInfo.price}"
                    multiDay: ${showInfo.multiDay}
                ) {
                    id
                }
            }
        `,
```

How do I edit this so that I also create relations between a `Show` that I am creating and appropriate `Venue` and `Artist` IDs?

Answer (score 0):

I had to structure the JSON so that I had access to a list of `Artist`s and a `Venue` at the time that I was writing a `Show`.

I then had to write each `Artist` and `Venue` (or validate whether these had already been written) to graphcool and get a respective ID back.

I then executed a function like the following:

```
async findShowOrCreate (showInfo, artists, venue) {
        const tempDate = new Date(showInfo.date);
        this.logger.info(`BEGIN : write show to graphcool (${showInfo.venue} on ${tempDate.toDateString()})`);

        const showQuery =   `
                                query ($venueId: ID!, $date: DateTime) {
                                    allShows(filter: {
                                            venue: {
                                                id: $venueId
                                            }
                                            date: $date
                                    })  {
                                            id
                                        }
                                }
                            `

        const existentialShowTest = await this.client.request(showQuery, 
            {venueId: venue, date: showInfo.date})

        if (existentialShowTest.allShows.length < 1){

            const addShowQuery =    `
                                        mutation createShow($artistsIds:[ID!], $venueId:ID  ) {
                                            createShow (
                                                artistsIds: $artistsIds
                                                venueId: $venueId
                                                date: "${showInfo.date}"
                                                soldOut: ${showInfo.soldOut}
                                                pit: ${showInfo.pit}
                                                ages: "${showInfo.ages}"
                                                price: "${showInfo.price}"
                                                multiDay: ${showInfo.multiDay}
                                            ) {
                                                id
                                            }
                                        }
                                    `
            const finalResult = await this.client.request(addShowQuery, 
                {venueId: venue, artistsIds: artists})
                .then(data => {
                 const result = data.createShow.id
                 this.logger.info(`FINISH: write show to graphcool as ${result}`)
                 return result
                })
                .catch(error => this.logger.error(error));

            return finalResult

        } else {
            this.logger.info(`FINISH: found show in graphcool`)
            return existentialShowTest.allShows[0]
        }

    }
```

which first ran a query to make sure that a `Show` representing the union of a specific date and `Venue` didn't already exist in graphcool, then ran a mutation to add a `Show`.

Note that this mutation was specifically structured to take in Ids for existing `Venue` and `Artist` objects (the latter in list form) and to attach these as variables in the line:

```
 client.request(addShowQuery, 
            {venueId: venue, artistsIds: artists})
```

using the `graphql-request` library, which allows you to pass a hash of variables into requests to graphcool.